# Using preprocessing directive #define for long long

Tags: c++, c++14, preprocessor-directive, long-long

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long

int main() {
    
    int a = 5;
    ll maxi = 1;
    maxi = max(maxi, maxi * ll(a));
    cout<<maxi<<endl;
    return 0;
    
}
```

Why does this code throw an error? I don't understand what's wrong with #define ll long long .

Comment: use int64_t in place of long long

Comment: Use typedef instead well me too learned something new that's #define ll long long is invalid :)

Comment: I would just type `int64_t ` instead of `ll`. Yes I know its a few extra characters but it improves readability

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that `#define` performs a textual substitution. You end up with this:

```
maxi = max(maxi, maxi * long long(a));
```

Which is invalid, since the type name for a functional cast can't, roughly speaking, contain spaces at the top level. So, `unsigned int(a)`, `long double(a)`, etc, are all invalid for this the same reason.

The solution is either to use `using` instead of `#define`:

```
using ll = long long;
```

or to do `(ll)a`, since in this case the spaces are allowed.

But if I were you, I would get rid of `ll` and use `(long long)a`, since `ll` is a rather non-descriptive name.

---

Note that `#define ll long long` is a misuse of macros, and is bad for many reasons:

- It's confusing. From seeing `ll maxi = 1;`, a reasonable person would expect `ll` to be a type and `ll(a)` to work. And it would work if it wasn't a macro.
- The short name can conflict with things. If you put this `#define` in a header, and then include another header that uses the word `ll` for any purpose whatsoever, it will break.

  To avoid that, macros should have long scary ALL_CAPS names.

Macros should be the last nuclear option, used when everything else fails, not just when you don't feel like typing some extra letters.

It's something you see on competitive programming sites, but if you attempted this at an actual job, it would fail any sane code review.

Comment: This is correct, but I'll add that `typedef long long ll;` works too

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with `#define ll long long` (other than the possibility you'll confuse it with `11`), it does exactly what it's supposed to do.

However, the cast `ll(a)`, which translates to `long long(a)`, is invalid (no spaces allowed in this form).

You need to use `(ll)a`, which becomes `(long long)a`.

---

I should mention that it would be better to use type definitions to do this rather than `#define` statements. That would be one of:

```cpp
typedef long long ll
using ll = long long;
```

Answer (score -1):

Remember the type casting method at first we have to write the typename first with the braces and then the variable like this `(int)a`.

In your code you have misused the macros.You have to write the keyword first then the thing by which you wanna call the keyword like this `#define long long ll` Then you can use `long long` as `ll`. That was all issues that you have with your code.

Comment: *"we have to write the typename first"* Not necessarily. `int(a)` compiles, even though `long long(a)` doesn't. *"You have to write the keyword first"* I don't fully understand the idea, but `#define long long ll` is wrong. It would replace `long` with `long ll`, which makes little sense. (Not to mention that reusing keywords such as `long` as macro names are illegal, you must come up with your own names.) OP's original macro makes more sense.