# Find largest mode in huge data set without timing out

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, statistics

**Description**
In statistics, there is a measure of the distribution called the mode. The mode is the data that appears the most in a data set. A data set may have more than one mode, that is, when there is more than one data with the same number of occurrences.

Mr. Dengklek gives you N integers. Find the greatest mode of the numbers.

**Input Format**
The first line contains an integer N. The next line contains N integers.

**Output Format**
A row contains an integer which is the largest mode.

**Input Example**
6
1 3 2 4 1 4

**Example Output**
4

**Limits**
1 ≤ N ≤100,000

1≤(every integer on the second line)≤1000

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define ll long long

int main() {

    unsigned int N;
    while(true){
        cin >> N;
        if(N > 0 && N <= 1000){
            break;
        }
    }
    int arr[N];
    int input;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        cin >> input;
        if(input > 0 && input <=1000){
             arr[k] = input;
        }
        else{
            k -= 1;
        }
    }
    
    int number;
    int mode;
    int position;
    int count = 0;
    int countMode = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        number = arr[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] == number){
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if(count > countMode){
            countMode = count;
            mode = arr[i];
            position = i;
        }
        else if(count == countMode){
            if(arr[i] > arr[position]){
                mode = arr[i];
                position = i;
            }
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    cout << mode << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

I got a "RTE" (run time error) and 70 pts.

Here is the code which I got 80 pts but got "TLE" (time limit exceeded):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define ll long long

int main() {

    unsigned int N;
    while(true){
        cin >> N;
        if(N > 0 && N <= 100000){
            break;
        }
    }
    int arr[N];
    int input;
    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    {
        cin >> input;
        if(input > 0 && input <=1000){
             arr[k] = input;
        }
        else{
            k -= 1;
        }
    }
    
    int number;
    vector<int> mode;
    int count = 0;
    int countMode = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        number = arr[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] == number){
                ++count;
            }
        }
        if(count > countMode){
            countMode = count;
            mode.clear();
            mode.push_back(arr[i]);
        }
        else if(count == countMode){
             mode.push_back(arr[i]);
        }
        count = 0;
    }
    sort(mode.begin(), mode.end(), greater<int>());
    cout << mode.front() << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

How can I accelerate the program?

Comment: In the first one you're limiting N in the first loop to be 1000 but the question says it can go up to 100,000 - is that the problem? Apart from that it looks OK, except that it's O(n^2) but you might get away with that depending on the judge. I don't suppose you have an example test case that fails? Same comments about the second one - it looks like you've just changed the way you're tracking the max mode. (You can also use std::max_element for that rather than sorting.)

Comment: That all said, since you know all numbers in the array are <= 1000 you could just total up how many of each number you have as you read them in, rather than saving all of the input numbers individually.

Comment: @Rup and that would be the correct TLE-free solution, which would have complexity.

Comment: If you're beginner, why you're solving things from competitional website? Btw, if you have `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` an it works, you don't need any other standard includes

Comment: Well i'm beginner in context of competitive programming bruh, not absolute beginner

Comment: Okay now i got TLE, can you provide better algorithm

Comment: Either 1) sort the numbers, and then scan the array: you'll find duplicates of each value next to each other as you scan, or 2) don't save the individual numbers as you read them in: make an array of size 1001 and count the total of each number you read in in the array as you read them in.

Comment: `int arr[N];` is (1) not standard C++ and (2) is likely to overflow the stack on compilers that are too nice to rightfully refuse to compile this as they should.

Comment: Welcome on SO. I upvoted because your post contained a problem definition, a sample input, the expected output, the error (even if just an acronym from codechef) and a viable attempt at a solution. That is *a lot* you have got right for a first-time poster even if it was mostly copied from the web site, I guess ;-). Now cut the polite fluff and write a more focused title, and I'm looking forward to your next posts!

Comment: is that from codechef though? many sites use same error codes and I didn't found this one there, wanted to test my attempt X3

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Actually I just googled the acronyms and [found](https://www.quora.com/What-is-WA-RTE-CTE-and-TLE-on-CodeChef) they occur there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. Competitive programming is a weird beast were solutions assume limited resources, whaky amount of input data. Often those tasks are balanced that way that they require use of constant time alternate algorithms, summ on set dynamic programming. Size of code is often taken in consideration. So it's combination of math science and dirty programming tricks. It's a game for experts, "brain porn" if you allow me to call it so: it's wrong, it's enjoyable and you're using your brain. It has little in common with production software developing.

You know that there can be only 1000 different values, but there are huge number or repeated instances. All that you need is to find the largest one. What's the worst case of finding maximum value in array of 1000? O(1000) and you check one at the time. And you already have to have a loop on N to input those values.

Here is an example of dirty competitive code (no input sanitation at all) to solve this problem:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

using in = unsigned short;

array<int, 1001> modes;
in               biggest;
int              big_m;
int              N;

int main()
{   
    cin >> N;

    in val;
    while(N --> 0){
       cin >> val;
       if(val < 1001) { 
           modes[val]++; 
       }
       else 
           continue;
       if( modes[val] == big_m) {
           if( val > biggest )
               biggest  = val; 
       }
       else
       if( modes[val] > big_m) { 
           biggest  = val; 
           big_m =  modes[val];
       } 
    }
    
    cout << biggest;
    return 0;
}
```

No for loops if you don't need them, minimalistic ids, minimalistic data to store. Avoid dynamic creation and minimize automatic creation of objects if possible, those add execution time. Static objects are created during compilation and are materialized when your executable is loaded.

`modes` is an array of our counters, `biggest` stores largest value of int for given maximum mode, `big_m` is current maximum value in `modes`. As they are global variables, they are initialized statically.

PS. NB. The provided example is an instance of stereotype and I don't guarantee it's 100% fit for that particular judge or closed test cases it uses. Some judges use tainted input and some other things that complicate life of challengers, there is always a factor of unknown. E.g. this example would faithfully output "0" if judge would offer that among input values even if value isn't in range.

Comment: thanks for the advice, i'll do what you say in next time

Comment: though if i add input sanitation, will it add execution time? because, i think input sanitation is essential in this web

Comment: you're my lifesaver in terms of my homework lmao

Comment: @ra.coder it would , but it would be minor a addition, just some checks after `cin >> val`.  Technically there is one already that ensures that we would stay inside of array. it's just unclear what to do if encountering non-numbers or an out-of-range values. Note that things like `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` or 
`using namespace std;` are fine in competitive code but are no-no in "good code"

Answer (score 2):

As already noted, the algorithm implemented in both of the posted snippets has O(N<sup>2</sup>) time complexity, while there exists an O(N) alternative.

You can also take advantage of some of the algorithms in the Standard Library, like [`std::max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), which returns an

> iterator to the greatest element in the range [first, last). *If several elements in the range are equivalent to the greatest element, returns the iterator to the **first** such element*.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    constexpr long max_N{ 100'000L };
    long N;
    if ( !(std::cin >> N) or  N < 1  or  N > max_N  )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: Unable to read a valid N.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    constexpr long max_value{ 1'000L };
    std::array<long, max_value> counts{};
    for (long k = 0; k < N; ++k)
    {
        long value;
        if ( !(std::cin >> value)  or  value < 1  or  value > max_value )
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: Unable to read value " << k + 1 << ".\n";
            return 1;
        }
        ++counts[value - 1];
    }
    
    auto const it_max_mode{ std::max_element(counts.crbegin(), counts.crend()) };
    // If we start from the last...                 ^^                ^^
    std::cout << std::distance(it_max_mode, counts.crend()) << '\n';
    // The first is also the greatest.
    return 0;
}
```

[Compiler Explorer demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dKGGYM3f1)

---

> I got a "RTE" (run time error)

Consider this fragment of the first snippet:

```cpp
int number;
int mode;
int position;            //   <---     Note that it's uninitialized
int count = 0;
int countMode = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    number = arr[i];
    // [...] Evaluate count.
    if(count > countMode){
        countMode = count;
        mode = arr[i];
        position = i;   //  <---       Here it's assigned a value, but...
    }
    else if(count == countMode){    // If this happens first...
        if(arr[i] > arr[position]){
        //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^      Position may be indeterminate, here  
            mode = arr[i];
            position = i;
        }
    }
    count = 0;
}
```

---

Finally, some resources worth reading:

[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

[Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

[Using preprocessing directive #define for long long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649609/using-preprocessing-directive-define-for-long-long)

[Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)