# deque::end results in assertion failure

Tags: c++, deque, stddeque

I was coding some code which needs a deque of structs. Only after 300 lines of repeatedly debugged code and excessive over-engineering, I found out that using the deque::end function somehow doesn't work in this code.

Below is a simplified version of the code:

vvv  code   vvv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#define lli signed long long int

using namespace std;

typedef struct cityData
{
    lli height;
    lli index;

} cityData;

int main()
{
    deque<cityData> city;

    lli cityCount;
    cin >> cityCount;

    for (lli i = 1; i <= cityCount; i++)
    {
        cityData input;
        cin >> input.height;
        input.index = i;

        city.push_back(input);
    }

    cout << "firstIndex: " << city.begin()->index << endl;
    cout << "lastIndex: " << city.end()->index << endl;
}
```

vvv  Input  vvv

```
10
9 2 8 3 7 2 8 2 9 1
```

vvv  Output  vvv

```
firstIndex: 1

error: cannot dereference out of range deque iterator
code terminated with exit code 3.
```

any idea on how to solve the issue?

I wanted to create a code which contains a deque of structs, however, an error occured when I used the function deque::end on the program.

Comment: `end()`  in the standard library is defined as one element past the last valid element.

Comment: No tags in the title please. There is a special field for tags.

Comment: you should not `#define lli`, never.

Comment: @drescherjm oh shoot, thanks for the info, appreciate it!

Comment: Side notes: (1) [using namespace std](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice), (2) [#define lli signed long long int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649609/using-preprocessing-directive-define-for-long-long)

Answer (score 2):

[`deque::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/end) returns an iterator to an element past the last element, and it mustn't be dereferenced.

You can use [`deque::back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/back) to refer to the last element. (This returns a reference to an element, not an iterator)